# What is the difference between those terms: "Association" and "Relation"?

Tags: database-design, orm, associations, data-modeling

In the context of data modeling, what is the difference between those terms: "Association" and "Relation" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "relation" is the mathematical term for a "table".

An "association" is a relationship between two tables.

Comment: Except that SQL tables are not relations in the mathematical sense as soon as they have any nullable column.

Comment: It might be more precise to say that, in SQL, tables are used to represent relations.  In addition to the comment about NULLS above, you need to prevent duplicate rows in order to use tables like relations.  You can prevent duplicates by declaring a primary key.